# Identify insect/bug/fleas

Tags: bugs, bug-identification

Can you please help me identify this. I live in Orange County California. Today I came back home and the weather was hot, around 85, and saw this around my front door in large quantities. I’ve never seen these before. I have a baby child at home and I am a bit concerned [image] [image]

Comment: It looks a lot like a [stink bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halyomorpha_halys) to me, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: Thanks Greg! I used Picture Insect App and it is saying it is False Chinch Bug. I am not sure yet

Comment: Defintitely not a flea, louse or bedbug.

Comment: What is the size of the bug? In mm would be easiest but compared to a well known other bug might work.